# Displaying many-to-many as many-to-most-important-one

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, mysql-5.7

This probably has an answer somewhere, but I’m not even sure how to search for it.

I have a many-to-many relationship, and I want to display it as many-to-one with the “most important” one. For instance, this query

```
SELECT Country.CountryName, FlagColor.Color
FROM Country
JOIN FlagColor USING (CountryID)
WHERE ...;
```

would return

```
CountryName  |  Color

  Ireland    |  Green
  Ireland    |  Orange
  Ireland    |  White
   Italy     |  Green
   Italy     |   Red
   Italy     |  White
    USA      |  Blue
    USA      |   Red
    USA      |  White
```

I know `GROUP BY` can limit these to one color each, but it could be any one of them. I’ve decided Blue is the top color, followed by Red, then Green. So I want to modify the above query to return

```
CountryName  |  Color

  Ireland    |  Green
   Italy     |   Red
    USA      |  Blue
```

How can I do this? If it’s relevant, I’m using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: you have for a query to figure out a logic, so you must explain why italy gets red and not green, or why usa gets blue and not white, a program doesn't know the difference, you must explain it.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @nbk Because I want Blue to get priority over Red, which gets priority over Green. Are you asking me to express it in SQL terms? I’d love to, that’s why I’m asking how to.

Comment: @Nick Version 5.7, if that’s relevant.

Comment: @Frungi it's always relevant. MySQL 8 has far more functionality than the 5.x versions and better capabilities for solving this problem (as you can see in TheImpalers answer)

Comment: @Nick Okay. I left it out because SO says about tagging, “Only include version numbers, like `c#-4.0`, when absolutely necessary.”

Comment: MySQL is one of those situations where it does make a difference as MySQL 8 and 5.x versions are very different in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FIELD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) to apply an ordering to the colours according to your precedence, ordering them according to least preferred first (since `FIELD` returns 0 for a value not in the list, this ensures those values sort last of all). Then you can get the `MAX` value for each country and `JOIN` that to the `Country` and `FlagColor` tables to get the desired colour for each country:

```
SELECT c.CountryName, f.Color
FROM Country c
JOIN FlagColor f ON f.CountryId = c.CountryId
JOIN (
  SELECT CountryId, MAX(FIELD(Color, 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue')) ColorId
  FROM FlagColor 
  GROUP BY CountryId
) m ON m.CountryId = c.CountryId
   AND m.ColorId = FIELD(f.Color, 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue')
```

Output:

```
CountryName     Color
Ireland         Green
Italy           Red
USA             Blue
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mPgFP4T5vEEmqXHZq2MAYo/0)

Comment: This sounds like yes. Thanks!

Comment: I’d also just like to publicly thank the person who posted the deleted answer involving `row_number()`, which was only because I hadn’t mentioned a version number.